# "this" in function is undefined when exporting something

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following example works as expected, and `console.log(this)` returns methods, variables, etc

```
function foo() {
  console.log(this);
}

foo();
```

However, this does not:

```
export const something = 'anything';

function foo() {
  console.log(this);
}

foo();
```

In this case, `conosle.log(this)` is undefined. Why?

Comment: How are you running each example? What Node.js command line?

Comment: Really, if called as `foo()`, you should not expect any particular `this` context at all, because there is none.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you're running your first example without the `--experimental-modules` flag, but you're running your second example *with* the flag.

Code in ESM modules is always in strict mode. In strict mode, if you don't do something to set what `this` is during a call (which you don't with `foo();`), `this` within the call gets the value `undefined`. But in loose mode (sometimes called "sloppy" mode), `foo();` sets `this` to the global object during the call.

Comment: You are right; when I compile it the use of `"use strict"` is doing this.

Comment: How do I then have a context `this` inside a function? I'd like to call my function as `name()` but still have a context `this`; not necessarily the global `this`, but any `this`

Comment: @Kousha - See [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work). Basically, you call it as a method on an object (`obj.foo();`) or you use `call` or `apply` (`foo.call(valueForThis, arg1, arg2)` or `foo.apply(valueForThis, [arg1, arg2]);`).

Answer (score 0):

If can be helpfull

```
function foo() {
  console.log(this);
}

// main script 'this'
foo() 

// execute foo with 'this' set to {foo: 'bar'}
foo.bind({ foo: 'bar '})();

// execute foo with 'this' set to the very function 'foo'
foo.bind(foo)();
```